# npm script is ignoring arguments of grep command

Tags: node.js, bash, npm

I have handy command for looking for TODO notes in my files. It works fine directly from the command line (ubuntu).

This is the plain CLI command:

```sh
grep -lir --color --exclude-dir={node_modules,libs} --exclude=package.json 'todo'
```

And this its occurrence in package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    …
    "scripts": {
        "css:dev": "node tasks/postcss.js --mode development",
        "css:build": "node tasks/postcss.js --mode production",
        "js:dev": "webpack --mode development",
        "js:build": "webpack --mode production",
        "lint:css": "npx stylelint assets/css",
        "lint:js": "npx eslint assets/js",
        "images": "node tasks/images.js",
        "sprite": "node tasks/svgsprite.js",
        "todo": "grep -lir --color --exclude-dir={node_modules,libs} --exclude=package.json 'todo'"
    }
}
```

When running with npm or yarn it ignores the exlude parameter and runs through the node_modules folder.

I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Which version of `node` and `npm` are you using?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention the versions: node v10.15.3, npm 6.4.1, yarn 1.15.2

Comment: I've installed your version of `node` and it is working as expected when it is run within the `npm` script. I don't know why you encounter this behavior! One thing worth mentioning though is that `grep` exits with status code of `1` if it doesn't find a match and this is shown as a `ELIFECYCLE` error in `npm`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original command-line execution works because the `bash` shell expands the expression `--exclude-dir={node_modules,libs}` to `--exclude-dir=node_modules --exclude-dir=libs` before invoking `grep`.  `grep` is happy to take multiple `--exclude-dir` arguments and it will exclude directories that match any of the specified names.

The problem with the command in `package.json` arises because `npm` does not use `bash` to run the command.  It uses plain old `sh` to run the command.

On some systems `sh` is just another name for `bash`, and on those systems putting the original command in `package.json` will work.  Presumably Ahmed's system is one of those.

However, on other systems (notably Debian and its descendants) `sh` is *not* the same as `bash`.  On these systems `sh` is a much simpler shell, and it does not expand the `--exclude-dir={node_modules,libs}` expression.  So `grep` sees the unexpanded argument and thinks it's being told to exclude a directory whose name is literally `{node_modules,libs}`.  Obviously that's not going to produce the result you want.

There are two obvious ways to fix this.  One is to tell `npm` to tell `sh` to launch a `bash` shell to execute the original command:

```
  "todo": "bash -c \"grep -lir --color --exclude-dir={node_modules,libs} --exclude=package.json 'todo'\""
```

The other, which I prefer because it doesn't involve multiple levels of shell or nested/escaped quotes, is to explicitly specify both directory names in the command:

```
  "todo": "grep -lir --color --exclude-dir=node_modules --exclude-dir=libs --exclude=package.json 'todo'"
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution and especially for the explanation how npm scripts are run. This knowledge will help in future too.